# multicolors in canvas LineTo

Tags: html, canvas

```
function TrackGraphic(model, canvas) {
    //TrackModel
    this._model = model;
    this.draw = function(context) {
        var dx = Math.cos(this._model.startAngle + Math.PI / 2);
        var dy = Math.sin(this._model.startAngle + Math.PI / 2);

        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 10;
        context.moveTo(this._model.offsetX, this._model.offsetY);
        //CurvePoint
        var p;
        for (var d = 0; d < this._model.length; d += 1) {
            if (d > 1000) {

                console.log('2F2F2F');
                context.strokeStyle = "#2F2F2F" //"rgb(255,165,0)"; //0x2F2F2F

            } else {
                context.strokeStyle = "#FFF" //"rgb(255,165,0)"; //0x2F2F2F;
                console.log('FFFFFF');


            }
            p = this._model.getTrackPoint(d);
            context.lineTo(this._model.offsetX + p.x, this._model.offsetY + p.y)
        }
        context.stroke();
    }
}​
```

The above code produces the lines in the canvas. The line is one color, I want to at the beginning or in any municipal color was different. My code does not work: (why?. How to fix it?

Comment: either line sgments or use gradients for stright lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the color while you are constructing the path doesn't do anything. The color is applied only once, when `stroke()` is called, so the last `strokeStyle` you set will be the color of the entire line.

`beginPath()`, `moveTo()`, `lineTo()`, etc only create a path and that path itself has no color. Stroking or filling that path only ever apply a single color.

If you want a path that is multiple colors you will have to do one of two things:

Begin a path, do some number of lines, stroke it one color, and then begin another path that will be stroked with a different color. In other words:

```
// make a red line segment
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();
// Begin a new path and make this line segment green
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.stroke();
//etc
```

Or, depending on what you're doing you could also use a linearGradient

Comment: I've done such a thing to the test. So that the color for the entire canvas was the same ...